# OWIN can't validate token from additional IDP configured in ADB2C

Tags: oauth, azure-ad-b2c, owin

We have a functional app that can authenticate (and thus validate tokens) ADB2C users using OWIN middleware server side.
We have now configured ADB2C with an additional IDP (AD) so that our internal users can authenticate using their own credentials.
However we now face the issue that our current OWIN pipeline is unable to validate the tokens for the AD authenticated users. Anyone can point me in the right direction to get OWIN to accept these tokens as well?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
When validating the token you do need to pas in a list of valid issuers, adding AD in the chain added an issuer in the architecture. However the token shows ADB2C as issuer and AD as IDP, you still need to treat AD as an issuer and pass it in the list of valid Issuers.